# Build in ubuntu docker's container is different than in mac os

Tags: angular, macos, ubuntu, docker, angular-universal

I think there is a problem in my docker's configuration but I can not find that out.

I tried to use Angular Universal by following the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/universal#server-code) on my project. I used also hammerjs that calls **window** in its init function. The server-side rendering does not support that kind of object so it caused:

```
})(window, document, 'Hammer');
window is not defined
```

Thanks to @cyrilletuzi for his [hotfix](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/308#issuecomment-319720507), I moved `import 'hammerjs'` from **app.module.ts** to **main.ts** and it worked! Until now, it is ok on mac os.

But because of the limit of memory of my VPS on ubuntu, I have to build my project in local, using Docker. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y

WORKDIR /home
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o node.sh && chmod +x node.sh
RUN ./node.sh && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN chmod 755 $(which node)

RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.2 --unsafe-perm

COPY package.json /home
RUN rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /home
RUN cd /home
RUN ng build --prod 
RUN ng build --prod --app mpp-universal --output-hashing=none
RUN webpack --config webpack.server.config.js
```

This is how my build folder looks like:

```
- browser
- server
    + main.bundle.js
    + ...
- server.js
```

The problem is, it seems like I have a problem about cache. **import 'hammerjs'** is still in my **server/main.bundle.js** in docker ubuntu, but not anymore in the same file on my mac.

Maybe in docker, the build didn't take the **main.server.ts** but **main.ts**

Comment: did you rebuild your image with no-cache?: `docker build --no-cache -t name . `

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. I even try to access into the container, check if the "import hammerjs" is in main.ts and not in app.module.ts. And rebuild the project, but it is still cause the above error.

Comment: What if you check the file again on ubuntu. delete your container, delete the images, build the image again and start a new container form the image.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I tried ```docker run -d --name app -v $(pwd):/data app sleep infinity``` to keep the container alive and I checked these files on ubuntu. The source is the same but the built files are not the same